# Why would a nuget package reference a non package dll path?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

When I add a nuget package reference via the Nuget Package Manager the installed dll references an old dll that was included in the solution directory.

I've seen this problem before in Visual Studio 2013 and it was fixable by editing the project file and changing the HintPath to the correct package location.  Since upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 the HintPath is pointed to the correct package folder, so the fix no longer works.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

I've tried searching the project for the bad dll path but can't find it.  It has to be stored somewhere in the project.  Sooo frustrating! Any ideas? Thanks

Update
I'm trying to reference the [YouTube api dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/) package

Comment: What's the nuget package, and which DLL are we talking about?

Comment: @A.Abramov see update, thanks